# Apache Nifi SOCKS Proxy Setup

Tags: java, proxy, jsch, apache-nifi, socks

I try to access a SFTP Source with Apache Nifi. The processor does not contain proxy settings. Therefor I wanted to provide Proxy Details on Startup as JVM Parameters.

```
java.arg.16=-DsocksProxyHost="123.123.123.123"
java.arg.17=-DsocksProxyVersion=5
java.arg.18=-Djava.net.socks.username="MYUSERNAME"
java.arg.19=-Djava.net.socks.password="MYPASSWORD"
java.arg.20=-DsocksProxyPort=1080
```

This does not work. I could not find any implementation of jsch explicitly using a proxy in the nifi code on github 
https://github.com/apache/nifi/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=jsch&type=

The question is:
Is Jsch using the provide parameters internally?

Comment: Issue is independent of Nifi:
With a reference implementation of JSch SFTP [link](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Sftp.java.html) I could validate that it makes a difference if I provide the parameters or not. Still I get an Authentication failed exception. I have checked the credentials several times and even tried the -Duser.name="MYUSERNAME" parameter in addition. Where is the implementation of the System.getProperties with the above mentioned properties?

Answer (score 1):

The underlying SFTP library Jsch that NiFi uses has its own proxy implementations such as com.jcraft.jsch.ProxySOCKS5. It seems those classes do not use system properties such as -Duser.name.

Instead, proxy instances should be passed manually from client application code, that requires NiFi SFTP related processors change. If following example looks promising to work with your environment, too, then I recommend to create a JIRA ticket to request adding proxy support for SFTP processors from [Apache NiFi JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/NIFI).

I wrote an example code to confirm that Jsch SFTP client can use SOCKS5 proxy. Following code worked:

```
import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Proxy;
import com.jcraft.jsch.ProxySOCKS5;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.Vector;

public class TestSFTPProxy {

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        final JSch jsch = new JSch();
        Session session = jsch.getSession("ftp-user", "ftp-server-host");
        final Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        properties.setProperty("PreferredAuthentications", "publickey,password,keyboard-interactive");
        session.setConfig(properties);

        Proxy proxy = new ProxySOCKS5("proxy-host", proxy-port);
        proxy.setUserPasswd("proxy-user", "proxy-password");
        session.setProxy(proxy);

        session.setPassword("ftp-user-password");
        session.connect();

        ChannelSftp sftp = (ChannelSftp) session.openChannel("sftp");

        sftp.connect();
        System.out.println(sftp);

        Vector ls = sftp.ls("path");
        System.out.println(ls.get(0));

        sftp.disconnect();
        session.disconnect();
    }

}
```

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-4175 
There is already a ticket regarding proxy support. I commented on that and hope that SOCKS Proxy Configuration would also be implemented for SFTP.